# Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'CGFloat'

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a for loop but can't seem to understand how to get rid of this error

My code:

```
for i:CGFloat in 0 ..< 2 + self.frame.size.width / (movingGroundTexture.size().width) { 
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: movingGroundTexture)
        sprite.zPosition = 0
        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(i * sprite.size.width, 0)
        addChild(sprite)
    }
```

The error is on `for` line on `self.frame.size.width` and `(movingGroundTexture.aize().width)`

Comment: As far as I know the half-open range operator (..<) doesn't work with non-integer values at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot create a [`CountableRange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/countablerange) (or [`CountableClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/countableclosedrange)) with floating point types.

You either want to convert your `2 + self.frame.size.width / movingGroundTexture.size().width` to an `Int`:

```
for i in 0 ..< Int(2 + self.frame.size.width / movingGroundTexture.size().width) { 
    // i is an Int      
}
```

Or you want to use `stride` (Swift 2 syntax):

```
for i in CGFloat(0).stride(to: 2 + self.frame.size.width / movingGroundTexture.size().width, by: 1) { 
    // i is a CGFloat   
}
```

Swift 3 syntax:

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: 2 + self.frame.size.width / movingGroundTexture.size().width, by: 1) {
    // i is a CGFloat
}
```

Depends on whether you need floating point precision or not. Note that if your upper bound is a non-integral value, the `stride` version will iterate one more time than the range operator version, due to the fact that `Int(...)` will ignore the fractional component.

Answer (score 5):

You have to convert the right side of the range to an integer type, like `Int` or `UInt`:

```
for i in 0 ..< Int(2 + self.frame.size.width / (movingGroundTexture.size().width)) {
    ...
}
```