# Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands [Swift]

Tags: swift, cgfloat

I was programming in my Xcode project and suddenly I got a warning that this:

```
 for var i:CGFloat = 0; i<3; i++
```

"will be removed in Swift 3." It gave me an option to "fix" the code to Swift 3 syntax and switched it to this:

```
for i:CGFloat in 0 ..< 3 {
```

Now my code will not run and the error it gets "Binary operator '.<' cannot be applied to two '`Int`' operands.

Comment: Does your `i` need to be a `CGFloat`?

Comment: Similar question: [Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'CGFloat'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401102/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-int-and-cgfloat) (Not sure if an actual dupe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i in 0..<3 {
    let someFloat = CGFloat(i) // if you need a CGFloat
}
```

Check your spacing, remove the `CGFloat` type from the loop declaration.

Answer (score 2):

As @JAL stated, I don't think you can run a `for` loop with a `CGFloat`, but you also have a couple of options here.

You could use a `range` operator like so:

```
// i is used an int
for i in 0..<3 {
    let convertedI = CGFloat(i) // This converts i to a new value as a CGFloat 
}
```

You could also use `stride` in **Swift 2** and cast as a `CGFloat`:

```
// i is now a CGFloat 
for i in (0 as CGFloat).stride(to: 3, by: 1) {
    // No need to convert because i is now a CGFloat 
}
```

And finally, `stride` in **Swift 3**:

```
// i is an int in this scenario
for i in stride(from: 0, to: 3, by: 1) {
    let convertedI = CGFloat(i) // This converts i to a new value as a CGFloat 
}
```

**Update:**

Changed my Swift 2 `stride` to cast `i` as a `CGFloat`, thanks to @Hamish.

Comment: You can use actually `stride` directly with a `CGFloat` if you want

Comment: You're absolutely right! I'll update my answer accordingly.