# iOS v7.3.1 SpriteKit - For Loop Err Msg: Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2

Upgraded to iOS 7.3.1 last week and trying to recreate a game that worked fine prior to the upgrade. Now I'm getting the following error message:

[image: Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'CGFloat']

What's going on?

Comment: Please post your actual code instead of (or in addition to) a picture of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'CGFloat'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401102/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-int-and-cgfloat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to from a range with an `Int` and a `CGFloat`.  That won't work.  You also can't form a range with two `CGFloat`s.  So, what can you do?

You can use `stride`:

```
for i in CGFloat(0).stride(to: self.frame.size.width / (groundTexture.size().width), by: 1) {
```

---

`stride:to:by` does not include the "to" number.

So:

```
for i in 1..<10 {
```

is equivalent to:

```
for i in 1.stride(to:10, by: 1) {
```

`stride:through:by` does include the "through" number if it is reached exactly.

So:

```
for i in 1...10 {
```

is equivalent to

```
for i in 1.stride(through: 10, by: 1)
```

Stride is not limited to `Int` types.  It works with floating point types such as `Float`, `Double`, and `CGFloat`.

Comment: Thank you! The stride suggestion is perfect!