# SwiftData (SQLite wrapper) broken with Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I'm using SwiftData for SQLite access.

https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/blob/master/Storage/ThirdParty/SwiftData.swift

SwiftData is a SQLite wrapper coded in Swift. After Swift 3.0 and XCode 8 the following lines are broken. I'm sort of noobie with Swift so I would appreciate your help with fixing what is broken:

```
let text = UnsafePointer<Int8>(sqlite3_column_text(statement, index))
```

results to: "'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type."

```
return Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(blob), count: Int(size))
```

results to: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeRawPointer?)'"

```
return sqlite3_column_int(statement, index) != 0
```

results to: "'!=' produces 'Bool', not the expected contextual result type 'AnyObject?'"

```
let text = UnsafePointer<Int8>(sqlite3_column_text(statement, index))
```

Results to: "'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type."

```
for i: Int32 in 0 ..< columnCount += 1 {
```

Results to: "Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: '..<' returns immutable value"

All Help Appreciated!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25169265/1187415 for the `sqlite3_column_text` problems.

Comment: The last problem is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940937/error-in-for-loop-cgfloat (and why is there a `+= 1` in the loop at all?)

Comment: For the *"'!=' produces 'Bool', not the expected contextual result type 'AnyObject?'"* problem we would need to know more context: What does the function return?

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, forgot to add link to github for source code. Please see the edited post. I was wondering on the "+= 1" myself.

Comment: @MartinR For the `!= produces Bool, not the expected contextual result type AnyObject?` the function is (after XCode Swift 3.0 migration tool) `func getColumnValue(_ statement: OpaquePointer, index: Int32, type: String) -> AnyObject? {`

Comment: Since https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData is not maintained, why don't you switch to a Swift wrapper that is up to date, like https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift?

Comment: @GwendalRoué I have a lot of SwiftData access in my app. I figured it was easier to fix the 5 places that had gone wrong in Swift 2 -> 3 migration than started to use another wrapper. But I think I might have to give your suggestion a try since the 5 simple fixes aren't so simple after all. Even after I got the code to compile, it crashes immediately at dataaccess. I'm mad at Swift 3 design to cause me extra work without apparent payback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite3_column_int(statement, index)` returns an `Int32` and

```
sqlite3_column_int(statement, index) != 0
```

is a boolean value, so that makes no sense as the return value if 
an (optional) `AnyObject` is expected. You can wrap the integer into
a `NSNumber` instead:

```
func getColumnValue(_ statement: OpaquePointer, index: Int32, type: String) -> AnyObject? {
    let val = sqlite3_column_int(statement, index)
    return NSNumber(value: val)
}
```

Another option would be

```
func getColumnValue(_ statement: OpaquePointer, index: Int32, type: String) -> AnyObject? {
    return sqlite3_column_int(statement, index) as AnyObject
}
```

because in Swift 3, *anything* can be converted to `AnyObject`.
The difference is that in the second solution, the object can only be
converted back to the original number type `Int32`, but not to
`Int` or any other integer type.

For the other problems, see

- [Issue with UnsafePointer<Uint8> in SQLite project in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168030/issue-with-unsafepointeruint8-in-sqlite-project-in-swift)
- [Error in for loop CGFloat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940937/error-in-for-loop-cgfloat)