# Binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type int and int? Swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm new in swift and I've try this problem for a couple hour. Below my code :

```
if filteredCustomReqList != nil { /* [1] error in this line */
    for i in 0..<filteredCustomReqList?.count {
        tempObj = filteredCustomReqList[i] as! [AnyHashable: Any]
        bezeichString = tempObj?["bezeich"] as! String

        specialRequestLabel.text = ("\(filteredString), \(bezeichString!)")
        print (bezeichString!)
    }
}
```

the error say :

```
binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type int and int?
```

where :

```
var filteredCustomReqList: [Any]? /* = [Any]() */
```

if i using `var filteredCustomReqList: [Any] = [Any]()` the error is gone but my if condition is always true. How to get this fix ? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401102/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-int-and-cgfloat) but its not same with my case (its `int` and `CGFloat`) .

Any answer and sugestion will help for me. Thanks In Advance

Comment: The error appears to be on the `for` line, not the `if` line, correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Optional Binding `if let` to unwrap `filteredCustomReqList` Optional variable.

```
var filteredCustomReqList: [Any]?

if let filteredCustomReqList = filteredCustomReqList {
    for i in 0..<filteredCustomReqList.count {
        tempObj = filteredCustomReqList[i] as! [AnyHashable: Any]
        bezeichString = tempObj?["bezeich"] as! String

        specialRequestLabel.text = ("\(filteredString), \(bezeichString!)")
        print (bezeichString!)
    }
}
```

Comment: sory for late response. I've been try all answer and its work for me. But at last, i used this answer for my code. Thanks for every great answer

Comment: I'm very happy to hear that! :)

Answer (score 6):

You should use optional binding so you don't have an optional in the `for` line.

```
if let list = filteredCustomReqList {
    for i in 0..<list.count {
    }
}
```

Even better would be to use a better `for` loop:

```
if let list = filteredCustomReqList {
    for tempObj in list {
        bezeichString = tempObj["bezeich"] as! String
    }
}
```

But to do this, declare `filteredCustomReqList` properly:

```
var filteredCustomReqList: [[String: Any]]?
```

This makes it an array that contains dictionaries that have `String` keys and `Any` values.

Comment: I wish that `for` loops just didn't nothing when attempt to iterate a `nil` optional sequence

Comment: @Alexander But Swift is specifically designed to avoid that kind of functionality. If you want that kind of behavior ("ignoring" nils), use Objective-C.

Comment: Then allow some other syntax that introduces a conditional binding into a `for` loop, rather than requiring a whole if statement

Comment: @Alexander You could use the nil-coalescing operator: `for i in 0 ..< (myArray?.count ?? 0)`

Answer (score 6):

This line looks suspicious:

```
for i in 0..<filteredCustomReqList?.count {
```

In particular, `filteredCustomReqList?.count` is of type `Int?` (`Int` optional), due to optional chaining. That is, if the array `filteredCustomReqList` is non-nil it gives the value of its `count` property (i.e., its number of elements). But if `filteredCustomReqList` is `nil`, that is propagated and `filteredCustomReqList?.count` is `nil` too.

In order to encompass both possibilities, Swift uses the optional type `Int?` (which can represent both valid `Int` values and `nil`). 
It is **not equivalent** to `Int`, and thus **can not** be used in an expression that expexts two `Int`s (like the range in your `for` loop).

You can't have `Int?` as the upper bound your for loop range; it doesn't make sense. You should **unwrap** the array before looping:

```
if let count = filteredCustomReqList?.count {
    // count is of type "Int", not "Int?"
    for i in 0..<count {
        // etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

First, like other answers, you should unwrap the optional value before use it.

Always keep in mind, in swift don't treat Optional value just a special type of the value itself. They are whole different thing.

An Optional< T > is a structure of Optional which associate a value of T if it present, what it looked is is:

```
enum Optional< T > {
    case NIL
    case SOME(T)
}
```

Actually, in Swift you may better do the above like:

```
// if you don't need return any thing you can just use forEach
filteredCustomerReqList?.map { obj in 
    tempObj = obj as? [AnyHashable: Any]
    bezeichString = tempObj?["bezeich"] as? String
    specialRequestLabel.text = ("\(filteredString),\(bezeichString)")
    print(bezeichString)
}
```